# Filling 2D array with a MIDI pattern

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, p5.js

I am struggling with a simple fill of 2D array, following a pattern given by MIDI notes list [Midi Notes Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDsNk.png). Basically, what I need to do is to fill a full width and hight of a canvas with numbers from 0 - 127.

I know that the logic is flawed, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

```
  let m = 0
  let n = 0;
  let blockW = Math.floor(width/12)
  let blockH = Math.floor(height/10)

   for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (var x = blockW * m; x < blockW *(m+1); x++) {
                midiArray[x] = []
                for (var y = blockW * m; y < blockW *(m+1); y++) {
                    midiArray[x][y] = n          
                }  
            }   
     
        }
        m++  
        n++     
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Do you want to create a simple table to with 
row 1 : 0,1,..11 
row 2 : 12...23
...
row 10: 120..127 
if thats the case keep yr outer loop to 10 inner loop to 12 and keep a counter that starts from 0 after every assignment increment it. give a stop condition when counter hits 127. 
If not ignore i didnt understand the question.

Comment: It's not clear why you are storing the same value `n` in `blockW` x `blockH` positions in your array. That seems wildly inefficient. How are you using this 2D array? is the purpose to draw exactly what is seen in the linked image? Or are you doing something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're approaching the problem in an optimal way, but here's the minimal changes to make your code coherent:

```js
let midiArray = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();

  // There is no need for the extra variable m
  let n = 0;
  let blockW = Math.floor(width / 12);
  let blockH = Math.floor(height / 10);

  // j - rows (iterate over rows first so that n increases from left to right)
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    // i - columns
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      // When finding pixel positions for the current block use i and j which
      // indicate the column and row.
      for (var x = blockW * i; x < blockW * (i + 1); x++) {
        if (!midiArray[x]) {
          // When we're generating the pixels for the second row we will be
          // re-using the existing array at midiArray[x], so only initialize
          // this the first time we are populating pixels for each particular x
          midiArray[x] = [];
        }
        for (var y = blockH * j; y < blockH * (j + 1); y++) {
          midiArray[x][y] = n;
        }
      }
      // Increase n for each block (not just for each row)
      n++;
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  background('red');
  loadPixels();
  for (let x = 0; x < midiArray.length; x++) {
    if (midiArray[x]) {
      for (let y = 0; y < midiArray[x].length; y++) {
        set(x, y, color(map(midiArray[x][y], 0, 120, 0, 255)));
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for clarification!